# Events missing in Navigation bar dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

i use c# in visual studio 2017 ,i have navigation bar but in method and classes dropdown i can't see events , I've already checked Navigation bar checkbox in option it was checked , tried to enable and disable the navigation bar but still i can't see events in method and classes dropdown( if i'm not mistaking ) ,
here is the screenshot to clarify the question:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

So to register an event you have to go the designer and select the `Properties` pane (Step 1). Then you can select the `Events` tab (Step 2) and double click on the event you want to register. It will automatically generate a method for you and open the coding view. Hope this helps!